# Prevent Trello board members from deleting a card

Tags: trello, delete, permissions

Is it possible to prevent board members from deleting a card in Trello?

I have a board where access is restricted to members only, and as the board owner, I've created a card, but I've found other members can delete the card.

This is bad news, as the card disappears completely, and even deletes the related events from the activity log. Is there any way of restricting the delete function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there currently is no way to do this.  Permissions is something we may add later and I assume that it would be covered by that, but we don't have any time frame on when that might happen (and we might also charge for features like that).

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification. I'll look forward to the possibility of being able to pay for this option in the future. The downside of Trello having a `delete` option for us, is that because we are ISO9001 certified, all our work flows need to be accountable, and I know our quality department won't allow us to adopt software that allows our staff to delete a task (card) without trace.

Comment: You need full audit capabilities. We're familiar with that in FogBugz.

Comment: I've installed FogBugz for a client that hosts it locally, but I've got to be honest, I've never actually used it myself. I thought FogBugz was [vertical](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2012/01/06.html) software, specifically targeted at software developers, (which technically we are, however it isn't the focus of our business). We primarily need software to manage our tasks and processes. Thanks for the heads up though, I'll investigate that further.

Comment: ..and another challenge I've been itching to mention, is that whilst free products can be good (as Trello clearly is), trying to convince company directors that our data is safe when we don't have any sort of contract in place with FogCreek would also be a challenge. FogBugz of course would alleviate those concerns too.

Comment: @bryan two things. I didn't mean you should use fogbugz to replace trello. just that we're familiar with 9001 and so we know the restrictions you face. also, I am sure we'll offer a paid option for people where we could have a contract in place as well as other features too.  but that won't be anytime soon.

Comment: Since it's been 4 years. Is this still the case?